# Server Error in '/' Application - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm getting this error when the page loads. Not always happens, when I hit the refresh button the error is solved.

An item with the same key has already been added.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)+9381419
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(String name) +52     AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.IsScriptCombinable(ScriptEntry scriptEntry,  Boolean enableCdn) +27
 AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.WriteScripts(List`1 scriptEntries, TextWriter outputWriter, Boolean enableCdn) + 122                   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.GetCombinedRegisteredScriptContent(Boolean  enableCdn) +206
    AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.GetCombinedScriptContentHash(HttpContextBase context, String[] bundles, Boolean enableCdn) +18

AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.LoadScriptReferences(HttpContextBase context,    String[] bundles, Boolean forCombineAndMinify) +135

AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +215
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I hope the error is being addressed by the team as there doesn't seem to be much activity on either the posts referenced by @Eric J.

Answer (score 4):

The basic error indicates that two objects are being added to the same dictionary with the same key, which is now allowed.

The additional stack trace leads me to believe that you are adding two controls with the same name to your ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this may be a recent bug

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27684

https://bugnet.codeplex.com/discussions/542489

Using an older version of AjaxControlToolkit may help you move forward, until the issue is resolved.

Comment: The controls are in the same page or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Please post how you configure the ToolkitScriptCombiner.

Comment: <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: I'm using the toolkit for the the framework 4.0. If a use an older one does it work?

Comment: @user1594439: Try the previous release, September 2013 http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/112805

Comment: I already tried this and I doesnt worked. The error still apppear.